# React: If you set state in a request animation frame will react schedule rendering on the animation frame?

Tags: reactjs, requestanimationframe

I'm trying to understand the nuances of using something like a game loop inside of React (version 16+). I'm confused as to how React's rendering strategy conflicts (or doesn't conflict) with another rendering scheduler - in this case: request animation frame.

Refer to the following example where a game loop is used to set state:

```
class Loop extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { x: 0 };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let then = performance.now();
    const loop = now => {
      if (this.state.x < 400)
        window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
      const dt = now - then;
      then = now;
      this.setState(prevState => ({ x: prevState.x + (dt * 0.1) }));
    };
    loop(then);
  }

  render() {
    const { x } = this.state;
    return <div style={{
      backgroundColor: "green",
      height: "50px",
      width: `${x}px`
    }}></div>;
  }
}
```

Will this work similarly to if one had manipulated the DOM directly? Or, will react do something like batch state updates to render, defeating the purpose of using a request animation frame?

Answer (score 14):

That's what I thought when answering this question: [How to implement a gameloop with requestAnimationFrame across multiple React Redux components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54066805/how-to-implement-a-gameloop-with-requestanimationframe-across-multiple-react-red/54145709#54145709)

As [`setState` is asynchronous](https://medium.com/@wereHamster/beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3), there's actually no guarantee that when calling it React is going to perform the update and re-render the component, on the contrary, React could just push that update to a queue that will process at some point, which might actually be in the next frame or later.

I profiled a really simple application using `requestAnimationFrame` to see if that was the case and actually it is not:

```js
class ProgressBar extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      progress: 0,
    };
  }
  
  update() {
    this.setState((state) => ({
      progress: (state.progress + 0.5) % 100,
    }));
  }  

  render() {
    const { color } = this.props;
    const { progress } = this.state;
    
    const style = {
      background: color,
      width: `${ progress }%`,
    };
    
    return(
      <div className="progressBarWrapper">
        <div className="progressBarProgress" style={ style }></div>
      </div>
    );  
  }
}

class Main extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    const progress1 = this.progress1 = React.createRef();
    const progress2 = this.progress2 = React.createRef();
    const progress3 = this.progress3 = React.createRef();
    
    this.componentsToUpdate = [progress1, progress2, progress3];
    this.animationID = null;    
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {  
    this.animationID = window.requestAnimationFrame(() => this.update());  
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.cancelAnimationFrame(this.animationID);
  }
  
  update() {
    this.componentsToUpdate.map(component => component.current.update());
  
    this.animationID = window.requestAnimationFrame(() => this.update());  
  }
  
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <ProgressBar ref={ this.progress1 } color="magenta" />
        <ProgressBar ref={ this.progress2 } color="blue" />     
        <ProgressBar ref={ this.progress3 } color="yellow" />       
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 16px;
}

.progressBarWrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid black;
  height: 32px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.progressBarProgress {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Here you can see how the updates are added to the queue (`enqueueSetState`), but the work is done straight away and all the calls to `update`, `setState`, `render`, `commitWork`... happen in the same frame:

[image: Example app profiling result]

However, I suspect that in a real application where React has more updates to handle or in future versions of React with features like time slicing, async updates with priorities... this might actually not be the case.